# GLIBC install failed, programs are missing or too old

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I had tried to install glibc-2.15 with non-root, after googling and trying two days,  I am looking help here.

```
After configure, it output following error:
../glibc-2.15/configure --prefix=${PWD/objDir/destDir}
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
configure: running configure fragment for add-on libidn
configure: running configure fragment for add-on nptl
checking for assembler gnu_indirect_function symbol type support... yes
checking whether .text pseudo-op must be used... yes
checking for assembler global-symbol directive... .globl
checking for assembler .type directive prefix... @
checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/x86_64/elf nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux nptl/sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/common sysdeps/unix/mman sysdeps/unix/inet nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 nptl/sysdeps/unix sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64/fpu sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch nptl/sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic/elf sysdeps/generic
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as is GNU as... yes
checking whether /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
checking version of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as... 2.25.1, ok
checking for /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
checking version of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld... 2.25.1, ok
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking for gcc... gcc
checking version of gcc... 4.9.3, ok
checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... gmake
checking version of gmake... 4.2.1, bad
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... gmsgfmt
checking version of gmsgfmt... 0.18.3, ok
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking version of makeinfo... 4.13, ok
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.2.1, ok
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for autoconf... autoconf
checking whether autoconf works... yes
configure: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

and in configure.log:

```
cat config.log
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Library configure (see version.h), which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../glibc-2.15/configure --prefix=/home/zhongxm/glibc/destDir

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = mercury
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.0.6-gentoo
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Sun Dec 11 16:24:12 CST 2011

/usr/bin/uname -p = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7450 @ 2.40GHz
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/zhongxm/bin
PATH: /home/zhongxm/local/bin
PATH: /home/zhongxm/bin/x86_64
PATH: /home/zhongxm/bin/scripts
PATH: /home/zhongxm/tool/jdk/bin
PATH: /home/zhongxm/tool/bedtools/bin
PATH: /home/zhongxm/tool/annovar
PATH: /home/zhongxm/tool/ngsShoRT
PATH: /home/zhongxm/tool/qualimap
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /opt/bin
PATH: /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3
PATH: /opt/svn/bin
PATH: /usr/local/meme/bin
PATH: /data/tool/hisat
PATH: /rd1/user/zh2yyongxm/bin
PATH: /rd1/user/zhongxm/script/
PATH: /rd1/user/zhangsj/bin
PATH: /rd1/user/data/bin/x86_64/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2367: checking build system type
configure:2381: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2401: checking host system type
configure:2414: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2483: checking for gcc
configure:2499: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2510: result: gcc
configure:2739: checking for C compiler version
configure:2748: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2759: $? = 0
configure:2748: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.9.3/work/gcc-4.9.3/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/python --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4' --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --disable-libgcj --enable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libcilkrts --enable-lto --without-cloog --enable-libsanitizer
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4)
configure:2759: $? = 0
configure:2748: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2759: $? = 1
configure:2748: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2759: $? = 1
configure:2764: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2786: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:2790: $? = 0
configure:2811: result: o
configure:2815: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2834: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:2834: $? = 0
configure:2843: result: yes
configure:2852: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:2872: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:2872: $? = 0
configure:2913: result: yes
configure:2930: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:2994: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:2994: $? = 0
configure:3007: result: none needed
configure:3077: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:3108: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:3108: $? = 0
configure:3122: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:9:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:3122: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:3147: result: gcc -E
configure:3167: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:3167: $? = 0
configure:3181: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:9:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:3181: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:3268: checking for g++
configure:3284: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:3295: result: g++
configure:3322: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:3331: g++ --version >&5
g++ (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3342: $? = 0
configure:3331: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.9.3/work/gcc-4.9.3/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/python --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4' --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --disable-libgcj --enable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libcilkrts --enable-lto --without-cloog --enable-libsanitizer
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4)
configure:3342: $? = 0
configure:3331: g++ -V >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3342: $? = 1
configure:3331: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3342: $? = 1
configure:3346: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:3365: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3365: $? = 0
configure:3374: result: yes
configure:3383: checking whether g++ accepts -g
configure:3403: g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3403: $? = 0
configure:3444: result: yes
configure:3949: running configure fragment for add-on libidn
configure:3949: running configure fragment for add-on nptl
configure:4091: checking for assembler gnu_indirect_function symbol type support
configure:4107: result: yes
configure:4110: checking whether .text pseudo-op must be used
configure:4120: gcc  -c conftest.s 1>&5
configure:4123: $? = 0
configure:4134: result: yes
configure:4138: checking for assembler global-symbol directive
configure:4151: gcc  -c conftest.s 1>&5
configure:4154: $? = 0
configure:4162: result: .globl
configure:4173: checking for assembler .type directive prefix
configure:4189: gcc  -c conftest.s 1>&5
configure:4192: $? = 0
configure:4200: result: @
configure:4223: checking sysdep dirs
configure:4468: result: sysdeps/generic/elf sysdeps/generic
configure:4545: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:4613: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:4628: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4632: result: yes
configure:4656: checking whether /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as is GNU as
configure:4670: result: yes
configure:4675: checking whether /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld is GNU ld
configure:4689: result: yes
configure:4699: checking for /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
configure:4726: result: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
configure:4741: checking version of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
configure:4751: result: 2.25.1, ok
configure:4762: checking for /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
configure:4789: result: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
configure:4804: checking version of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
configure:4814: result: 2.25.1, ok
configure:4829: checking for pwd
configure:4847: found /bin/pwd
configure:4860: result: /bin/pwd
configure:4878: checking for gcc
configure:4905: result: gcc
configure:4920: checking version of gcc
configure:4930: result: 4.9.3, ok
configure:4941: checking for gnumake
configure:4971: result: no
configure:4941: checking for gmake
configure:4957: found /usr/bin/gmake
configure:4968: result: gmake
configure:4983: checking version of gmake
configure:4993: result: 4.2.1, bad
configure:5005: checking for gnumsgfmt
configure:5035: result: no
configure:5005: checking for gmsgfmt
configure:5021: found /usr/bin/gmsgfmt
configure:5032: result: gmsgfmt
configure:5047: checking version of gmsgfmt
configure:5057: result: 0.18.3, ok
configure:5068: checking for makeinfo
configure:5084: found /usr/bin/makeinfo
configure:5095: result: makeinfo
configure:5110: checking version of makeinfo
configure:5120: result: 4.13, ok
configure:5131: checking for sed
configure:5147: found /bin/sed
configure:5158: result: sed
configure:5173: checking version of sed
configure:5183: result: 4.2.1, ok
configure:5234: checking for readelf
configure:5250: found /usr/bin/readelf
configure:5261: result: readelf
configure:5288: checking for autoconf
configure:5304: found /usr/bin/autoconf
configure:5315: result: autoconf
configure:5330: checking whether autoconf works
configure:5341: result: yes
configure:5350: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_PWD_P=/bin/pwd
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AS=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
ac_cv_prog_AUTOCONF=autoconf
ac_cv_prog_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -E'
ac_cv_prog_LD=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
ac_cv_prog_MAKE=gmake
ac_cv_prog_MAKEINFO=makeinfo
ac_cv_prog_MSGFMT=gmsgfmt
ac_cv_prog_SED=sed
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_READELF=readelf
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes
libc_cv_asm_global_directive=.globl
libc_cv_asm_gnu_indirect_function=yes
libc_cv_asm_type_prefix=@
libc_cv_autoconf_works=yes
libc_cv_dot_text=.text
libc_cv_nss_crypt=no
libc_cv_prog_as_gnu=yes
libc_cv_prog_ld_gnu=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar'
AS='/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as'
ASFLAGS_config=''
AUTOCONF='autoconf'
AWK=''
BASH_SHELL=''
BISON=''
BUILD_CC=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXFLAGS='-g -O2'
CXX_SYSINCLUDES=''
DEFINES=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_INFO=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
KSH=''
LD='/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBGD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKE='gmake'
MAKEINFO='makeinfo'
MIG=''
MSGFMT='gmsgfmt'
OBJCOPY='/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objcopy'
OBJDUMP='/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objdump'
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Library (see version.h)'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='glibc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='(see version.h)'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PWD_P='/bin/pwd'
READELF='readelf'
RELEASE=''
SED='sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SYSINCLUDES=''
VERSION=''
VERSIONING=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
add_on_subdirs=' libidn'
add_ons='libidn nptl'
all_warnings=''
base_machine='x86_64'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
bindnow='no'
bounded='no'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
cross_compiling='no'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
elf='yes'
enable_check_abi='no'
exceptions=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
fno_unit_at_a_time=''
force_install='yes'
gnu89_inline=''
have_libaudit=''
have_libcap=''
have_selinux=''
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
ldd_rewrite_script=''
libc_cv_Bgroup=''
libc_cv_as_i686=''
libc_cv_as_needed=''
libc_cv_cc_avx=''
libc_cv_cc_fma4=''
libc_cv_cc_novzeroupper=''
libc_cv_cc_sse4=''
libc_cv_cc_submachine=''
libc_cv_cc_with_libunwind=''
libc_cv_cpp_asm_debuginfo=''
libc_cv_forced_unwind=''
libc_cv_fpie=''
libc_cv_gcc_static_libgcc=''
libc_cv_gcc_unwind_find_fde=''
libc_cv_hashstyle=''
libc_cv_have_bash2=''
libc_cv_have_initfini=''
libc_cv_have_ksh=''
libc_cv_libgcc_s_suffix=''
libc_cv_localedir=''
libc_cv_nss_crypt='no'
libc_cv_output_format=''
libc_cv_pic_default=''
libc_cv_rootsbindir=''
libc_cv_slibdir=''
libc_cv_ssp=''
libc_cv_sysconfdir=''
libc_cv_z_combreloc=''
libc_cv_z_execstack=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mach_interface_list=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
multi_arch='default'
nopic_initfini=''
old_glibc_headers=''
oldest_abi='default'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
omitfp='no'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/zhongxm/glibc/destDir'
profile='no'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
shared='default'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sizeof_long_double=''
static='yes'
static_nss='no'
subdirs='  '
submachine=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
sysdeps_add_ons=' nptl'
sysnames=' sysdeps/x86_64/elf nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux nptl/sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/common sysdeps/unix/mman sysdeps/unix/inet nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 nptl/sysdeps/unix sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64/fpu sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch nptl/sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic/elf sysdeps/generic'
target_alias=''
use_default_link='default'
use_ldconfig=''
with_fp='yes'
xcoff='no'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
#define HAVE_LIBIDN 1
#define ASM_GLOBAL_DIRECTIVE .globl
#define ASM_TYPE_DIRECTIVE_PREFIX @
#define USE_MULTIARCH 1

configure: exit 1
```

I had checked that programs mentioned in INSTALL is newer than it needed. Considering my software may too new, I had install make-3.79 which is mentioned in INSTALL, gcc texinfo, but they didn't solved my problem. I hardly know what to do? Is any other way can I install GLIBC without root privileges.

The related information of my machine:

```
uname -a
Linux mercury 3.0.6-gentoo #1 SMP Sun Dec 11 16:24:12 CST 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7450 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

gcc --version
gcc (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.4, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

texi2pdf --version
texi2dvi (GNU Texinfo 4.13) 1.135

Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Any suggestion would be grateful!
Best wishes!

Edit:

Mrak Plotnick, thanks for your reply very much!

According to your suggestion, it output new error as follow, could you give me another advice?

```
../glibc-2.15/configure --prefix=${PWD/objDir/destDir} --disable-multilib
........
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
../misc/syslog.c: In function '__vsyslog_chk':
../misc/syslog.c:123:30: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline 'syslog': function not inlinable
 ldbl_strong_alias (__syslog, syslog)
                              ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:102:26: note: in definition of macro '_strong_alias'
   extern __typeof (name) aliasname __attribute__ ((alias (#name)));
                          ^
../sysdeps/generic/math_ldbl_opt.h:12:44: note: in expansion of macro 'strong_alias'
 #define ldbl_strong_alias(name, aliasname) strong_alias (name, aliasname)
                                            ^
../misc/syslog.c:123:1: note: in expansion of macro 'ldbl_strong_alias'
 ldbl_strong_alias (__syslog, syslog)
 ^
In file included from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syslog.c:10:0:
../misc/syslog.c:155:3: error: called from here
   syslog(INTERNALLOG,
   ^
make[2]: *** [/home/zhongxm/glibc/v2/objDir/sysd-rules:1311: /home/zhongxm/glibc/v2/objDir/misc/syslog.os] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/zhongxm/glibc/v2/glibc-2.15/misc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:220: misc/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/zhongxm/glibc/v2/glibc-2.15'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

Also, I had tried to installed latest gcc (which install latest gmp, mpfr and mpc first) and glibc, but when I add the path of lib in glib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it output "Segmentation fault", any other suggestions?

Any suggestion would be grateful! Best wishes!

Comment: This may work: edit the `configure` file, look for `3.79* | 3.[89]*`, change it to `3.79* | 3.[89]* | 4.*`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As new information is too long, I post them below.

Answer (score 1):

Your make is old. Compile and install GNU make, and create a soft link of gmake to make.

Comment: This will not solve the problem.  the problem comes about because the file `configure` has a hard-coded check for the make version as described by @Mark Plotnick which only allows make versions between 3.79 and 3.99.  Getting a newer version of make will not solve this problem.

To solve this, while trying to build a system that relies on a old `configure` file requires modifying the `configure` file to allow make versions of 4 or greater.